# Vue CLI npm run build throws Syntax Error: Unexpected token - but code looks fine

Tags: javascript, syntax-error, vue-cli

I am getting the following error when I try to `npm run build` my Vue app:

```
Syntax Error: Unexpected token (559:18)
    
      557 |         async, allGroups(), {
      558 |             const: theAttendees = await groupsModule.attendeesFromGroups,
    > 559 |             this: .currentAttendees.push(theAttendees)
          |                   ^
      560 |         }, async, logout(err), {
      561 |             alert() { }
      562 |         } `Logout err : ${err}`);
```

The code in the error makes no sense to me with all the commas after everything, the `const:` and `this:`, and especially the `alert() { }` which doesn't reflect what the code is at all.

This is what the code itself looks like. I cannot see anything wrong.

```
  async allGroups() {
    const theAttendees = await groupsModule.attendeesFromGroups
    this.currentAttendees.push(theAttendees)
  }

  async logout(err){
    alert(`Logout err : ${err}`)
    console.log('DASHBOARD: logout')
    await userModule.logout();
  }
```

If anyone has any ideas what this syntax error actually is referring to I'd be very grateful for the help.

Comment: const theAttendees = await groupsModule.attendeesFromGroups(); <-- missing paranthesis

Answer (score 0):

You might be missing comma after the function allGroups() ends
your code will be like

```
 async allGroups() {
  const theAttendees = await groupsModule.attendeesFromGroups();
  this.currentAttendees.push(theAttendees)
 },
  async logout(err){
    alert(`Logout err : ${err}`)
    console.log('DASHBOARD: logout')
     await userModule.logout();
  }
```

Comment: Thanks but it's not a comma problem.

Answer (score 0):

**NOTE**: This is not the issue, see the comment, using Vuex functions, so don't need parenthesis

```
const theAttendees = await groupsModule.attendeesFromGroups(); <-- missing paranthesis
```

Comment: If that's all the issue is, it's better to comment and vote to close as a typo

Comment: Thanks for the response, but that is not the issue. The functions are imported  via Veux modules and don't require parentheses.